# CMD - Move files to the folders dependent on the list?

Tags: list, cmd, move

I have a list (list.txt) like this with the content:

> C:\Users\Computers\39323227
>   C:\Users\Computers\39323227.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39328635
>   C:\Users\Computers\39328635.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39329113.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39329288.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39331075
>   C:\Users\Computers\39331075.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39331386.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39904282
>   C:\Users\Computers\39904282.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39905798
>   C:\Users\Computers\39905798.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39906307.zip

And all files and created folders in parent folder clutter like this:

> C:\Users\Computers\39323227
>   C:\Users\Computers\39328635
>   C:\Users\Computers\39331075
>   C:\Users\Computers\39904282
>   C:\Users\Computers\39905798
>   C:\Users\Computers\39323227.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39328635.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39329113.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39329288.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39331075.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39331386.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39904282.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39905798.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39906307.zip

Is it possible to write a CMD to move files to folders as the below? :

> C:\Users\Computers\39323227\39323227.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39328635\39328635.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39328635\39329113.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39328635\39329288.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39331075\39331075.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39331075\39331386.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39904282\39904282.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39905798\39905798.zip
>   C:\Users\Computers\39905798\39906307.zip

If not, could you suggest that there are any soft which could help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I recommend looking into windows schell scripting.  It is easy to pick up.  you will create a *.bat file.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q22540287.txt) DO (
 IF "%%~xa"==".zip" (
rem  ECHO MD "!destdir!\" 
  ECHO MOVE "%%a" "!destdir!\"
 ) ELSE (SET "destdir=%%~dpna")
)
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q22540287.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

I've added in a line to ensure that the selected destination directory exists. To activate that feature, remove the `REM` from the `MD...` line. The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

Results for me (noting that I changed `C:` to `U:` for my testing)

```
MOVE "u:\Users\Computers\39323227.zip" "u:\users\computers\39323227\"
MOVE "u:\Users\Computers\39328635.zip" "u:\users\computers\39328635\"
MOVE "u:\Users\Computers\39329113.zip" "u:\users\computers\39328635\"
MOVE "u:\Users\Computers\39329288.zip" "u:\users\computers\39328635\"
MOVE "u:\Users\Computers\39331075.zip" "u:\users\computers\39331075\"
MOVE "u:\Users\Computers\39331386.zip" "u:\users\computers\39331075\"
MOVE "u:\Users\Computers\39904282.zip" "u:\users\computers\39904282\"
MOVE "u:\Users\Computers\39905798.zip" "u:\users\computers\39905798\"
MOVE "u:\Users\Computers\39906307.zip" "u:\users\computers\39905798\"
```